# Navegando entre URLs com Javascript (alterando valor da url)

Tags: javascript, html

Boa noite, estou tentando fazer um comando em javascript que redirecione para uma página html e adicione uns caracteres no texto final, exemplo:

> index.html

após o comando (pega o valor anterior do link e adiciona +abcd no final):

> indexabcd.html

E se fosse uma pagina com outro nome, por exemplo:

> joao.html

Com o comando ficaria:

> joaoabcd.html

Agradeço a quem ajudar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso aqui deve resolver.

```js
var urlAnterior = document.referrer;
//remove o .html
urlAnterior = urlAnterior.replace('.html','');
var complementoURL = "abcd";

function comando(){
  window.location.href = urlAnterior+complementoURL+".html";
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="comando()">Comando</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Com uma pequena combinação de substrings você consegue, se todos os links terminarem com a extensão do arquivo, apenas procure pelo ultimo ponto e adicione o texto escolhido atrás

- **lastIndexOf**: Para ver onde está o último ponto.
- **Substring**: Para pegar tudo que está antes do último ponto.
- **Substr**: Para pegar a extensão novamente, poderia ser o Substring de novo, mas é um parâmetro a menos.

Resultado:

```
function mudarLink (link, texto){ 
  ultimoPonto = link.lastIndexOf('.');
  return link.substring(0, ultimoPonto) + texto + link.substr(ultimoPonto)
}
```